# Android 4.0 GC inconsistency- Bitmaps are not freed

Tags: android, bitmap, garbage-collection

I know this subject has been discussed a lot, but I can't find workaround/solution for my memory problem.

Problem is that in android 4.0 garbage colletor does not work (at least I am starting to believe so). Below is a snapshot traces from acer iconia tablet(4.0, 48M heap) and motorola defy(2.2, 30M heap) about same situation in my code. That is, get next stage from game -> ditch the old images and load new ones to memory.

4.0

```
08-15 21:33:07.020: V/ThemePacket(25564): debugSaveMemInfo: D:23.61  N:2.12  O:2.65

08-15 21:33:07.020: ThemePacket(25564): ClearBitmapsFromMemory: 7 friends  20 foes  2 GFIs

08-15 21:33:07.050: D/dalvikvm(25564): GC_EXPLICIT freed 4K, 74% free 10909K/41671K, paused 2ms+3ms

08-15 21:33:07.260: V/ThemePacket(25564): debugSaveMemInfo: D:23.61  N:2.12  O:2.65

08-15 21:33:07.260: V/DrawableResourceDataReference(25564): Bitmap size is: w:1875 h:1250 Asking for: w:1215 h:780

08-15 21:33:07.280: D/dalvikvm(25564): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 36K, 74% free 10940K/41671K, paused 18ms

08-15 21:33:07.410: I/dalvikvm-heap(25564): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 9375016-byte allocation

08-15 21:33:07.450: D/dalvikvm(25564): GC_BEFORE_OOM freed <1K, 74% free 10940K/41671K, paused 44ms

08-15 21:33:07.510: E/dalvikvm-heap(25564): Out of memory on a 9375016-byte allocation.
```

2.2

```
08-15 22:10:53.132: V/ThemePacket(15074): GetStage(1)

08-15 22:10:53.155: V/ThemePacket(15074): debugSaveMemInfo: D:2,73  N:3,36  O:15,97

08-15 22:10:53.155: V/ThemePacket(15074): ClearBitmapsFromMemory: 7 friends  20 foes  2 GFIs

08-15 22:10:53.218: D/dalvikvm(15074): GC_EXPLICIT freed 911 objects / 115904 bytes in 54ms

08-15 22:10:53.241: V/ThemePacket(15074): debugSaveMemInfo: D:2,73  N:3,36  O:9,02

08-15 22:10:53.241: V/DrawableResourceDataReference(15074): Bitmap size is: w:1875 h:1250 Asking for: w:885 h:600

08-15 22:10:53.241: V/DrawableResourceDataReference(15074): Scaling down by 2

// all goes fine
```

Note these lines:

```
debugSaveMemInfo: D:23.61  N:2.12  O:2.65
ClearBitmapsFromMemory: 7 friends  20 foes  2 GFIs
debugSaveMemInfo: D:23.61  N:2.12  O:2.6
```

vs.

```
debugSaveMemInfo: D:2,73  N:3,36  O:15,97
ClearBitmapsFromMemory: 7 friends  20 foes  2 GFIs
debugSaveMemInfo: D:2,73  N:3,36  O:9,02
```

And to decrypt those traces a bit, this is how I get the memory info:

```
Debug.MemoryInfo memInfo = new Debug.MemoryInfo();
Debug.getMemoryInfo(memInfo);
double nativeMem = memInfo.nativePss/(double)1024;
double otherMem = memInfo.otherPss/(double)1024;
double dalvikMem = memInfo.dalvikPss/(double)1024;
//some formatting...
Log.v(LOG_TAG, "debugSaveMemInfo: D:" + dalvik + "  N:" + nativeM + "  O:" + other);
```

Clear bitmaps from memory beef looks like this:

```
// Bitmap mBitmap
mBitmap.recycle();
mBitmap = null;
```

and yes, I have debugged the code in both platforms and everything goes exactly the same way in my code. So if anyone is still reading this, some questions arise. Why recycling bitmaps in 4.0 does not free any memory? Isn't the GC suppose to be finding every bits of free memory before throwing OoM? If I reduce the amount of memory used totally, so that I prevent OoM, those bitmaps are eventually freed. But not when I would need the memory...

To make things more interesting, I took a hprof file from case where the ghost bitmaps are in memory and you know what, they are not! Memory analyzer says that dalvik heap is about 10M at the same moment when I print those 23M figures to the screen and get OoM from that 9M allocation. I am kind of out od ideas here so any suggestions are welcome. I guess my next solution is to lower the image quality if I get OoM

Comment: Right, so after some hard thinking, I now think that Debug.MemoryInfo is just sort of slow in 4.0. (I tried to reserve and free memory while that problem was occurring and neither show up in MemoryInfo). The original problem is still there though, but the reason is more likely a heap fragmentation than actual GC failing. Unfortenately I did not find any good workaround for that. So I just scale the image down when I catch OoM and user is left with blurry background. Next time big image is fetched, heap is magically corrected and everything works again